# Java 8 flatmap , stream,collect

Tags: java, java-8

I have a situation where I have

```
class A {
    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

and another class B

```
class B {
    private List<C> c;

    public List<C> getListC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Now class C contains two instance variables

```
class C {
     private int id;
     private String name;

     public int getId() { 
         return id;
     }

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }
}
```

Now I want to achieve the below using java 8

```
List<C> newListC = a.getB().getListC();
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

for(C c : newListC) {
  map.put(c.getId,c.getName());
}
```

I have tried many time but every time I face different problems.
My code:

```
    Optional<A> a=Optional.of(new A());
    Map<Integer, String> map= a.map(A::getB)
                            .flatMap(b ->
                                    b.getListC()
                                            .stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                        C::getId,
                                        C::getName
                                                    )
                                            )
                            );
```

Error message  :

```
Error:(164, 33) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type
variable(s) U,R,A,capture#1 of ?,T,K,U exist so that
java.util.Optional<U> conforms to
java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `a.getB().getListC().stream().collect(toMap(C::getId, C::getName))`. You're over-thinking this.

Comment: What @BoristheSpider meant was `Collectors.toMap`, unless he did a static import, but for here it's better to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: @boris maybe post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t `flatMap` an `Optional` to a `Map`; the function has to return an `Optional`. On the other hand, since the function doesn’t return an `Optional`, a `flatMap` is unnecessary and an ordinary `map` will do:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Optional.of(new A())
    .map(A::getB)
    .map(b -> b.getListC().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, C::getName)))
    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```

But since the result of `new A()` can’t be null (and using `of` instead of `ofNullable` acknowledges this), the indirect processing at the beginning of the chain is unnecessary:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Optional.ofNullable(new A().getB())
    .map(b -> b.getListC().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, C::getName)))
    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```

But note that only the nullability of the result of `getB` is handled, as the function passed to the next mapping step unconditionally invokes `stream()` on the list returned by `getListC`. But returning `null` where a `List` is expected is bad coding style anyway; you can always return an empty list to represent the absence of values.

Maybe your confusion stems from a `Stream` based alternative solution:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Stream.of(new A().getB())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(b -> b.getListC().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, C::getName));
```

Here, a stream consisting of at most one element is created, followed by `flatMap`ing it to the items of the list returned by `getListC`…

Answer (score 2):

Though I hit couple of compilation errors as I can see few typos, but

Try:

```
    List<C> newListC= new A().getB().getListC();

    Map<Integer, String> stringMap = newListC.stream()
            .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(C::getId, C::getName));
```

Provided that you fixed your compilation issues, it should be emitting result equivalent to non-stream version of map.

Comment: I can not use List<C> newListC= new A().getB().getListC(); I want to keep it in series of map or flatMap as directly using this can give null pointer exception

Comment: As I mentioned, there are compilation errors so it's not possible to give you accurate solution. Please see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve